# Relativistic collision

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, spacetime

Suppose you have the system $S'$ with velocity $V=\frac{4}{5}c$ relative to $S$, and you have positioned a random particle at the position $x'=1 \: ls$. $S$ and $S'$ have set their clocks to $0$ at the same position. Now a photon leaves from the origin of $S'$ at $ct'=3 \: ls$ . This photon at a certain time $ct_1'$ hits the mass M, where the photon is completely absorbed by $m$ and a new particle is created. Suppose you want to know at what "time" $ct_1'$ this happens. How would you determine this?

What appears is that to get $ct_1'$ you can sum $ct'+x'$, so it would be $ct_1'=4 \: ls$? I am having a hard time imagining this summation. In fact, I am trying to somehow link it to the $x,\:y$ system but is not a good way I guess. Can anyone draw a picture of this for me? Or am I simply thinking too hard? My concern here, of course, is not the answer but the idea of why the summation is possible because I can't imagine anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you're overthinking it, for example: what is the point of $S$? I'm just going to set $S=S'$ and write coordinates in $S$ as (t, x).

The particle's world line is ($c=1$):

$$ p_0(t) = (t, 1) $$

While the photon's is (for $t\ge 1$):

$$ p_1(t) = (1, 0) + (t-1, t-1) = (t, t-1)$$

which intersects $p_0$ when:

$$ p_1(t) = p_0(t) $$
$$ (t, t-1) = (t, 1) $$

so that $t=2$.

You can draw those lines on a Minkowski diagram, which is plotted with $x$ along the x-axis and $t$ along the y-axis.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the mention the speed of $S'$, it is: $V=\frac{4}{5}c$ relative to $S$. Then you cannot state that $S=S'$, right?

Comment: Okay, forget what I said before. Only system $S'$ is relevant to this question indeed

Comment: I was indeed thinking too hard. Indeed, drawing a Minkowski diagram already helps a lot.

Comment: regarding another frame: once you have a list of events, $E_i=9(t_i, x_i)$ you can confidently Lorentz transform them to another frame, and ponder what they look like from there.